# Ошибка в Qt: undefined reference to `_imp__GetPixel@12'

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qt5

При использовании функции из Winapi 32 - GetPixel, получаю ошибку при компиляции: 
ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__GetPixel@12' collect2.exe:-1: 
ошибка: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
inline int getcolor(int x, int y, HWND hwnd=0) {
    HDC hdc =(hwnd ==0) ? GetDC(st->getHWND()) : GetDC(hwnd);
    int color = GetPixel(hdc, x, y); //тут прекращает компилирываться и
    return color;                    //вылетает     
}
```

Заголовочные файлы подключил:windows.h и wingdi.h подключил. Компилятор MinGW 5.3.0 32bit2 Возможно надо подкл. библиотеку Gdi32.lib, только я не знаю где ее искать.

Comment: Ну подключите прямо в исходнике - `#pragma comment(lib,"gdi32")`

Comment: Не помогает стабильно ошибка при компиляции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не подключил библиотеку lgdi32. Я написал в pro файле проекта:

```
LIBS += -lgdi32
```

Все заработало.